# Can't submit form/log-in to Nike.com using headless browser in python

Tags: python, html, forms, browser, urllib2

I am currently trying to do some QA/form submissions using a headless browser in python, and I don't think my libraries are able to submit/complete the form. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

response1 = br.open("http://www.nike.com/us/en_us/")

assert br.viewing_html()
print br.title()
print response1.geturl()

html = response1.read()

for forms in br.forms():
    print forms

# Select the second (index one) form
br.select_form('login-form')

# User credentials
br.form['email'] = 'example@email.com'
br.form['password'] = 'test-password'


br.submit
```

If I try robobrowser, this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cmw/PycharmProjects/Nike_Bot/nike_bot_py.py", line 44, in <module>
    browser.submit_form(signin_form)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/robobrowser/browser.py", line 341, in submit_form
    response = self.session.request(method, url, **payload.to_requests(method))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 553, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 608, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'javascript:void(0);'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you are trying to access runs javascript to submit forms: `action="javascript:void(0);"`. Your `mechanize` library is trying to mimic that without actually being able to understand javascript and fails. If you just submit the content of the form with a POST then that may work unless they are using request authentication, in which case you are out of luck.

Comment: So I'm guessing I need to use a headless browser that submits these forms as if I'm literally clicking them?

Comment: I'm not aware of any programmable browser that runs javascript. Just try to send a request that acts as if you filled out the form without actually navigating the page.